# I have created a dynamic CheckBoxList and completed it in Page_Load. Now I can't get selected items

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my checkBoxList:

```html
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="2" Style="float: left; font-size: large;"></asp:CheckBoxList><br />
```

When i select an item and press the button i gets an error System.IndexOutOfRangeException

I use this line to show selected item

```
 System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(CheckBoxList1.SelectedValue[0])
```

Thank you!

**EDIT**

dobraKartaOdp.First() - string value;
zlaKartaOdp.First() - string value;

```
            Random rnd = new Random();
        for ( int i = 0; i< 20; i++)
        {
            if(rnd.Next(0,2) == 1 && dobraKartaOdp.Count != 0)
            {
                wyjKartaOdp.Add(dobraKartaOdp.First());
                dobraKartaOdp.RemoveAt(0);
            }
            else if(rnd.Next(0, 2) == 0 && zlaKartaOdp.Count != 0)
            {
                wyjKartaOdp.Add(zlaKartaOdp.First());
                zlaKartaOdp.RemoveAt(0);
            }
            else
            {
                i = i - 1;
            }
        }
        CheckBoxList1.DataSource = wyjKartaOdp;
        CheckBoxList1.DataBind();
```

[This is my test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/to9Hj.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have just declared a checkbox list.
You need to bind items to it or give it a datasource .
Its a checkbox list you need to iterate through every item and select those which are checked like ::

```
 foreach (ListItem li in CheckBoxList1.Items)
            {
                if (li.Selected == true)
                {
                  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(li.value);
                }

            }
```

Comment: Actualy i use this to get all selected item:             List<String> zazOdp = CheckBoxList1.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                .Where(x => x.Selected == true)
                .Select(x => x.Value)
                .ToList();    but this list is always empty...

Comment: It will only return selected items

Comment: well i tested you metod and i don't get any result. All items are not selected

Comment: The code(Linq) you sent me is also working.

So ,can you show me how have you bind your checkbox list?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what your output is  but you should have the logic inside the button event in the code behind instead of the Page load. for example lets say you have 2 checkboxes and a button (make sure you put the onClick event on the button)

```
<fieldset style= 400px>
<asp:CheckBox ID="firstcheckbox" Text="firstcheckbox" runat="server"/>
<asp:CheckBox ID="secondcheckbox" Text="secondcheckbox" runat="server"/>
</fieldset>
<br/>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="submit" onClick="Button1_Click"/>
```

In your code behind make a a method for your submit button (remember the onClick event we have to use this button know or the code will crash)

so

```
protected void "Button1_Click (object sender,EventArgs e)
{

if(firstCheckbox.Checked)
{
//do something
}
if(secondCheckbox.Checked)
{
//do something
}


}
```